# Bootstrap 3 modal not opening in one click

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, laravel-5.8

my bootstrap 3 modal does not open up in one click everytime, sometimes it does not open up, sometimes it opens up after 2-3 mouse clicks, rarely it opens up in one click.

Basically I have trying to create a modal that will ask whether the user wants to delete it, if yes then send a post request to remove the value from the given database with the provided id in url.
It is a table of courses, all of them having its own delete button, and the id used is of the form  `id="deleteModal{{ $subtopic->subtopic_id }}"`

> this is my delete button

```
    <td class="col-1"><a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-trash"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal{{ $subtopic->subtopic_id }}"></i></a></td>
```

> this is my modal

```
   <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal{{ $subtopic->subtopic_id }}">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                                      <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                                          <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Course ?</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <div >
                                                <h4>Are you sure!</h4>
                                                <form action="{{ url('superadmin/allcourses/'.$course->course_id.'/'.$topics->topic_id.'/'.$subtopic->subtopic_id ) }}" method="post">
                                                    @csrf
                                                    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                                                    <div style="text-align: center;"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-check-double"></i>Yes</button> 
                                                        </div>
                                                </form>
                                            </div>   
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
```

It should always open up in one click, please help me out I can't find any reason why it happens.

Comment: you have used wrong id name convention "id="deleteModal{{ $subtopic->subtopic_id }}", try with id="deleteModal-SomeStringYouWant"

Comment: I have used blade syntax there is nothing wrong about it I guess

Comment: it returns "id="deleteModal1", "id="deleteModal2" etc like that as per the number of values in the foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the html as below in the td.

```
 <td class="col-1">
     <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal{{ $subtopic->subtopic_id }}">
         <i class="fas fa-trash">
         </i>
     </a>
 </td>
```

**data-target** does not work on `<i></i>`

Comment: thanks a lot I didn't saw that it was a typo looked at it so many times. I feel like a fool putting this question.